# AVR Assembly: Writing to arrays without returning anything

Tags: arrays, assembly, ld, avr, cpu-registers

I have to write a program in AVR assembly that takes in a pointer to an integer array when being called by a C program and performs operations on its elements without actually outputting values. For simplicity's sake, let's say I want my program to double the value of each element - Such that given the array `{2, 4, 6, 8}`, calling a print method in C separately from what I wrote will print `{4, 8, 12, 16}`.

My problem is I don't understand how to alter the values of the array's elements and have those changes persist after the function doing so has finished executing. I can't return anything through register `r24`, because I need to return a different number for a different purpose.

My idea was, since the input on register `r24` comes in as a pointer to the first element of the array, I would `mov r26 r24`,  associating(?) the array with the X pointer, and then `ld` that to another register so that I can use the X pointer to increment through the array, as in `ld r18, X+`.

And while I have little trouble navigating the array, I don't understand how to give my changes permanence, if that makes sense. I'm under the impression that I'm expected to use `st` and/or `sts` to solve this, but I'm struggling to understand how they work. My attempt was to reserve a pointer like Z to be associated with the input array, and every time I had a value ready to replace an old element in the array, I would write `st Z+, rXX`, putting the value at index Z and subsequently pointing to the next index. This didn't work, so I'm left wondering: what do I need to do to link the memory of my local registers with that of the inputs provided to the program?

Comment: `I don't understand how to give my changes permanence, if that makes sense` - this sounds weird. Your array is in memory, at sequential addresses. You pass the pointer to the start address and overwrite the content of this memory with new values - what can be more permanent than that. :)  It is worth specifying which C compiler you use as you will need to understand the compiler-specific 'calling convention'.  And, if in doubt, you can always implement your function in C instead of asm and see what compiler produced.

Comment: `This didn't work, so I'm left wondering` - well, as this really tells us almost nothing it is always recommended to show the actual code (by copy&paste into the question body, using [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55860409/edit)) Since you sound as someone with little experience there maybe dozens of reasons why something didn't work for you, no point guessing. Please also specify the exact chip that you are programming for (or the emulator if you're using one). `since the input on register r24` - i'm not experienced with AVR but a pointer is 16 bits, isn't it? can't be passed via r24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I encourage you to read [Application Note AT1886: Mixing Assembly and C with AVRGCC](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/doc42055.pdf) (pdf document)
It describes how parameters and return values are passed to and from called routines.

To make an assembly code callable from C you have to write a declaration stub for the assembly function. You may put it in `.h` file. Let it be a function with one pointer-type parameter and without return values.

```
extern void my_function(void *);
```

Keyword `extern` will tell the linker that the function body is somewhere else, not in this .c file

Now, you can add assembly file, creating new `.s` file in your project. On top of it you may put:

```
#define _SFR_ASM_COMPAT 1
#define __SFR_OFFSET 0

#include <avr/io.h>
```

Those declarations will make you able to access lower IO registers using instructions `in` / `out` / `cbi` / `sbi` etc.

Now you should declare a label which will be the same as a function name, and declare it `.extern`

```
 .extern my_function

 my_function:
   // assembly for the function body is here
```

As said in the appnote, first parameter is placed in r25:r24, (second, if any, in r23:r22, third in r21:r20, fourth in r19:r18). If you even have 1-byte parameter, it, all the same, will utilize two registers, r24 will store its value, while r25 will be left unused. Second parameter will be in r23:r22 etc.
If you have 4-byte value (`long int`, for example), then it will use two consequent parameter positions, i.e. it value will be stored in r23:r22:r25:r24

If your code uses registers r2-r17, also r28 or r29 (Y register), their previous values should be preserved and restored before return. Also it is recommended to preserve r0 (see table 5-1 in the appnote, but take into account there is misprint: `r0` at second from bottom line, above r31, should be read as `r30`)

register r1 always contains 0, if you somehow change it's value (calling `MUL` instruction, for example), then you have to clear it back before return.

So, considering our example, let assume you have some C code, which calls your assembler routine:

```
uint8_t my_array[10]; // declare an array

my_function(&my_array); // call the routine, passing pointer to the array
```

Then your function will be called and first parameter (registers r25:r24) will contain a pointer to the array. So, you assembly code can take it into any pointer register and do whatever you like. For example

```
 .extern my_function

 my_function:
   movw X, r24 // copy r25:r24 into X (r27:r26)
   ldi r18, 10
   st X+, r18 // store 10 into first element of the array
   ldi r18, 20
   st X+, r18 // store 20 into second element of the array
   ... etc

 ret // return
```

Now, when function is called as in example above, `my_array[0]` will contain 10, `my_array[1]` == 20, etc.